# displayNewAppointmentForm doesn't display in Mac Outlook Desktop

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We develop an Outlook Office Add-in that calls `displayNewAppointmentForm`

```
mailbox.displayNewAppointmentForm({ subject: 'subj text'}); //simplified
```

This works as expected in Outlook 2016 for Windows and OWA but not in Outlook 2016 for Mac version 15.39

No exception in thrown, the `displayNewAppointmentForm` returns normally but no calendar meeting pops up is displayed.

The documentation doesn't mention Mac is not supported. It does mention Outlook for iOS and Android are not supported with this method.

Is there a workaround for this problem ?

Comment: Could you add the code you're using to call `displayNewAppointmentForm` to your question?

Comment: We tested with a simplified call (added to question).

Comment: Thanks for raising it. It's bug in Mac outlook. We are working on it. Will update the thread once fix is out.